# LVM - Are disk labels /sda/sdb/... guaranteed to be different physical disks?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I'm looking at the output of `vgdisplay` and seeing 2 volume groups.

One for the `/dev/sdb` and one for `/dev/sdc`

They have different UUID's but identical sizes. Both 35TB. But one has been allocated 20TB and the other 15TB. Both show the remaining amounts as available for their volume group to be what you expect: 15TB for the first, 20TB for the second.

Is it possible that these 2 physical volumes are actually the exact same physical disk and 2 physical? Or am I being paranoid here?

How would I check this without physical access to the machine?

`fdisk -l` is showing identical sizes, but slight differences in bytes and sectors.

Is there a more "correct" or "complete" way to determine this?

Comment: These seem to be different disks. You can trust `fdisk -l`.

Comment: Ok. `lsblk` also shows different disks.